# Using bash script to remove some lines beginning with certain characters

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have a file in the following format:

```
--- V1 ---
Hi there
--- V2 ---
--- V3 ---
What's good
--- V4 ---
--- V5 ---
--- V6 ---
```

I want to use some kind of bash script to remove any of the lines beginning with three dashes that are not immediately followed by a line that does NOT have three dashes, e.g.:

```
--- V1 ---
Hi there
--- V3 ---
What's good
```

I can easily remove ALL of the lines beginning with dashes, but don't know how to do it based on the following line (or alternatively, based on the line preceding the non-dashed lines).

Comment: Probably not an answer to your question, but a 1 line partial solution - grep -v -B1 "^---" file.name  will look for all lines which don't start with  "---", and display those lines and line line immediately prior to it.  This will only work if each payload line is followed and preceded by a line with "---", ie won't work over multiple lines.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a bash script? Something like this could be done with sed, grep, awk, or even vim.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a bash script, no. Doesn't using grep not disqualify it from being a bash script, though?

Comment: @davidgo Your answer actually worked for multiple lines correctly, so if you want to make it an answer then feel free and I'll mark it correct. Otherwise I will accept Gombai Sandor's answer, which is more complex but also correct.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think Gombai Sandors answer is pretty cool so I upvoted it, but I added mine because I think its a lot easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -v -B1 "^---" file.name
```

Will look for all lines which don't start with "---", and display those lines.  "-B1" displays the line immediately prior.

Answer (score 2):

I guess "some kind" means that you don't insist on pure bash. If so, then awk can do it well:

```
/tmp$ input="--- V1 ---
Hi there
--- V2 ---
--- V3 ---
What's good
--- V4 ---
--- V5 ---
--- V6 ---"
/tmp$ echo "$input" | awk '/^---/ {row = $0; if (wasdashed) next; wasdashed=1; next}; { if (wasdashed) print row; print $0}'
--- V1 ---
Hi there
--- V3 ---
What's good
/tmp$
```

Anyway, with the very same logic, pure bash would be possible, but with much more coding.

Comment: This gives completely different output for me; --- V1 --- is repeated after every line, but is otherwise the same output as input.

Comment: @Birdie Make sure to drop the leading spaces when copy/pasting the above example. Works fine then.